# ¿Por qué pygame no actualiza el valor en un archivo?

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy creando un juego en donde cada vez que colectas una moneda (esto sucede dentro del ciclo principal) se actualiza un contador el cual a su vez está guardado en un archivo de texto (este archivo solamente contiene el número 0 en la primera linea) y el cual esta definido dentro de mi función principal, pero fuera de mi ciclo. El problema es que no se actualiza y no sé por qué razón.

Aquí esta el código:

```
'Importación de librerías'
import pygame
import random
import time
pygame.init()

'Declaración de variables globales'
ANCHO = 800  # Ancho de la pantalla
ALTO = 600  # Alto de la pantalla

'Colores'
# Color         #R       #G      #B
Blanco = (255, 255, 255)
Negro = (0, 0, 0)
Rojo = (255, 0, 0)
Azul = (0, 0, 255)

'Estados'
MENU = 1
JUGANDO = 2

'Función para dibujar al personaje'


def dibujarPersonaje(ventana, imagen, x, y):
    ventanaDeJuego = ventana  # Se define la pantalla de juego
    imagenMario = imagen  # Se define la imagen del personaje
    x = x  # Posición en 'x' de la imagen del personaje
    y = y  # Posición en 'y' de la imagen del personaje
    ventanaDeJuego.blit(imagenMario, (x, y))  # Se dibuja al personaje en la ventana


'Función que dibuja al primer obstáculo'


def dibujarObstaculoUno(ventana, imagen, xObstaculo, yObstaculo):
    ventanaDeJuego = ventana  # Se define la pantalla de juego
    imagenObstaculo = imagen  # Se define la imagen del obstáculo
    x = xObstaculo  # Posición en 'x' de la imagen
    y = yObstaculo  # Posición en 'y' de la imagen
    ventanaDeJuego.blit(imagenObstaculo, (x, y))


'Función que dibuja al segundo obstáculo'


def dibujarObstaculoDos(ventana, imagen, xObstaculo, yObstaculo):
    ventanaDeJuego = ventana  # Se define la pantalla de juego
    imagenObstaculo = imagen  # Se define la imagen del obstáculo
    x = xObstaculo  # Posición en 'x' de la imagen
    y = yObstaculo  # Posición en 'y' de la imagen
    ventanaDeJuego.blit(imagenObstaculo, (x, y))


'Función que dibuja al tercer obstáculo'


def dibujarObstaculoTres(ventana, imagen, xObstaculo, yObstaculo):
    ventanaDeJuego = ventana  # Se define la pantalla de juego
    imagenObstaculo = imagen  # Se define la imagen del obstáculo
    x = xObstaculo  # Posición en 'x' de la imagen
    y = yObstaculo  # Posición en 'y' de la imagen
    ventanaDeJuego.blit(imagenObstaculo, (x, y))


'Función que dibuja a la moneda'


def dibujarMoneda(ventana, imagen, xMoneda, yMoneda):
    ventanaDeJuego = ventana  # Se define la pantalla de juego
    imagenMoneda = imagen  # Se define la imagen de la moneda
    x = xMoneda  # Posición en 'x' de la imagen
    y = yMoneda  # Posición en 'y' de la imagen
    ventanaDeJuego.blit(imagenMoneda, (x, y))


'Función para puntos'


def hacerPuntaje(ventana, monedasAcumuladas):
    ventanaDeJuego = ventana
    fuenteTexto = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    texto = fuenteTexto.render("Monedas recolectadas: " + str(monedasAcumuladas), True, Negro)
    ventanaDeJuego.blit(texto, (0, 0))


'Función para dibujar los botones'


def dibujarBotones(ventana, x, y, ancho, alto, imagenUno, imagenDos, accionClick=None):
    ventanaDeJuego = ventana  # Se carga la ventana
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()  # Obtiene la posición del mouse para poder...
    # ...actualizar la imagen

    if x + ancho > mouse[0] > x and y + alto > mouse[1] > y:  # Se pregunta respecto la posición del mouse
        ventanaDeJuego.blit(imagenDos, (x, y))  # Se actuliza la imagen del botón
    else:
        ventanaDeJuego.blit(imagenUno, (x, y))  # Si no pasa nada, no se actualiza


'Función para dibujar la pantalla de GameOver'


def dibujarPerdio(ventana, imagen, sonido):
    sonido.play()
    imagenPerdio = imagen  # Se define la imagen del personaje
    ventanaDeJuego = ventana  # Se define la pantalla de juego
    ventanaDeJuego.blit(imagenPerdio, (0, 0))  # Se dibuja la imagen
    pygame.display.update()  # Se actualiza el display de pygame
    time.sleep(3)  # Se establece cuánto tiempo se quiere ver esta pantalla
    dibujarJuego()  # Se lleva al jugador al menu


def dibujarPuntaje(archivoMonedas):
    imagenPuntos = pygame.image.load("fondoPuntos.png")
    ventanaDeJuego = pygame.display.set_mode((ANCHO, ALTO))
    ventanaDeJuego.blit(imagenPuntos, (0, 0))
    fuenteTexto = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)
    texto = fuenteTexto.render("La mayor cantidad de monedas que has conseguido son: " + str(archivoMonedas), True,
                               Negro)
    textoDos = fuenteTexto.render("¿Puedes superarte?", True, Negro)
    ventanaDeJuego.blit(texto, (100, 270))
    ventanaDeJuego.blit(textoDos, (320, 310))
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(3)
    dibujarJuego()


'Estructura del programa (se dibuja todo lo anterior'
def dibujarJuego():
    ventanaDeJuego = pygame.display.set_mode((ANCHO, ALTO))  # Se crea la pantalla
    pygame.display.set_caption("Mamma mia! It's a kart!")  # Nombre del juego
    logo = pygame.image.load("Logo.png")  # Se carga la imagen para el logo
    pygame.display.set_icon(logo)  # Logo en ventana
    reloj = pygame.time.Clock()  # Limitar FPS

    ### Imágen del personaje ###
    imagenMario = pygame.image.load("marioJuego.png")  # Se carga la imagen
    anchoImagen = 80  # De la imagen, se obtiene el ancho
    x = ANCHO * 0.45  # Posición en 'x'
    y = ALTO * 0.8  # Posición en 'y'
    cambioEnX = 0  # Contador para actualizar posición
    ### Imágen del personaje ###

    ### Imágen obstáculo ###
    imagenObstaculo = pygame.image.load("obstaculo.png")  # Se carga la imagen
    anchoObstaculo = 80  # De la imagen, se obtiene el ancho
    altoObstaculo = 70  # De la imagen, se obtiene el alto
    xObstaculo = random.randrange(0, ANCHO)  # Posición en 'x'
    yObstaculo = -600  # Posición en 'y'
    velocidad = 10  # Velocidad de caída del objeto

    imagenObstaculoDos = pygame.image.load("obstaculoDos.png")  # Se carga la imagen
    anchoObstaculoDos = 80  # De la imagen, se obtiene el ancho
    altoObstaculoDos = 70  # De la imagen, se obtiene el alto
    xObstaculoDos = random.randrange(0, ANCHO)  # Posición en 'x'
    yObstaculoDos = -650  # Posición en 'y'
    velocidadDos = 0.5  # Velocidad de caída del objeto

    imagenObstaculoTres = pygame.image.load("obstaculoTres.png")  # Se carga la imagen
    anchoObstaculoTres = 80  # De la imagen, se obtiene el ancho
    altoObstaculoTres = 70  # De la imagen, se obtiene el alto
    xObstaculoTres = random.randrange(0, ANCHO)  # Posición en 'x'
    yObstaculoTres = -650  # Posición en 'y'
    velocidadTres = 0.1  # Velocidad de caída del objeto
    ### Imágen obstáculo ###

    ### Imágen moneda ###
    imagenMoneda = pygame.image.load("moneda.png")  # Se carga la imagen
    anchoMoneda = 80  # De la imagen, se obtiene el ancho
    altoMoneda = 70  # De la imagen, se obtiene el alto
    xMoneda = random.randrange(0, ANCHO)  # Posición en 'x'
    yMoneda = -600  # Posición en 'y'
    velocidadMoneda = 20  # Velocidad de caída del objeto
    ### Imágen moneda ###

    ### Puntaje Monedas ###
    monedasColectadas = 0  # Se establece el contador de monedas
    ### Puntaje Monedas ###

    ### Imágenes de fondo y botones ###
    fondoJuego = pygame.image.load("fondoNivelBase.png")
    fondoPerdio = pygame.image.load("FondoPerdio.png")
    fondoMenu = pygame.image.load("fondoMenu.png")
    botonJugar = pygame.image.load("jugarUno.png")
    botonJugarDos = pygame.image.load("jugarDos.png")
    botonSalirUno = pygame.image.load("salidaUno.png")
    botonSalirDos = pygame.image.load("salidaDos.png")
    botonPuntosUno = pygame.image.load("puntosUno.png")
    botonPuntosDos = pygame.image.load("puntosDos.png")
    ### Imágenes de fondo y botones ###

    ### ANIMACIÓN MENU ###
    imagenMarioMenu = pygame.image.load("marioMenu.png")  # Se carga la imagen delpersonaje como animación en Menú
    xMario = -200  # Se establece la posición del personaje en 'x'
    yMario = 500  # Se establece la posición del personaje en 'y'
    ### ANIMACIÓN MENU ###

    ### ESTADO ###
    estadoJuego = MENU
    ### ESTADO ###

    ### AUDIO ###
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("Juego.wav")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    sonidoColision = pygame.mixer.Sound("Colision.wav")
    sonidoMoneda = pygame.mixer.Sound("Moneda.wav")
    sonidoPerdio = pygame.mixer.Sound("GameOver.wav")
    sonidoPuntos = pygame.mixer.Sound("Puntos.wav")
    sonidoJugar = pygame.mixer.Sound("Jugar.wav")
    ### AUDIO ###

    ### ARCHIVO ###
    archivoPuntos = open("Puntos.txt", "r")

    puntosOriginales = archivoPuntos.readline()

    archivoPuntos.close()

    puntosJugador = 0
    ### ARCHIVO ###



    terminado = False  # ¿Se acabó el juego?, NO

    pygame.init()
    ### CICLO PRINCIPAL ###
    while not terminado:
        for evento in pygame.event.get():
            if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()  # El jugador quiere salir del juego
                quit()

            ### Movimiento de la imagen con teclado ###
            if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if evento.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    cambioEnX -= 15
                elif evento.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    cambioEnX += 15

            if evento.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if evento.key == pygame.K_LEFT or evento.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    cambioEnX = 0
            ### Movimiento de la imagen con teclado ###

            ### MOUSE ###
            elif evento.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                xm, ym = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                anchoBoton = 150
                altoBoton = 50
                xBotonUno = 150
                yBotonUno = 360
                xBotonDos = 480
                yBotonDos = 360
                xBotonTres = 310
                yBotonTres = 420
                if xm >= xBotonUno and xm <= xBotonUno + anchoBoton and ym >= yBotonUno and ym <= yBotonUno + altoBoton:
                    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                    sonidoJugar.play()
                    estadoJuego = JUGANDO
                elif xm >= xBotonDos and xm <= xBotonDos + anchoBoton and ym >= yBotonDos and ym <= yBotonDos + altoBoton:
                    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                    sonidoPuntos.play()
                    dibujarPuntaje(puntosOriginales)
                elif xm >= xBotonTres and xm <= xBotonTres + anchoBoton and ym >= yBotonTres and ym <= yBotonTres + altoBoton:
                    terminado = True

            ### MOUSE ###
        if estadoJuego == MENU:
            ventanaDeJuego.blit(fondoMenu, (0, 0))  # Dibuja Menu
            dibujarBotones(ventanaDeJuego, 150, 360, 150, 50, botonJugar, botonJugarDos)  # Dibuja botón
            dibujarBotones(ventanaDeJuego, 480, 360, 150, 50, botonPuntosUno, botonPuntosDos)  # Dibuja botón
            dibujarBotones(ventanaDeJuego, 315, 420, 150, 50, botonSalirUno, botonSalirDos)  # Dibuja botón
            ventanaDeJuego.blit(imagenMarioMenu, (xMario, yMario))  # Dibuja personaje
            xMario += 5  # Se actualiza la posición del personaje
            if xMario > ANCHO + 30:  # Si sale de la pantalla la imagen...
                xMario = -200  # ...su posición 'x' se reinicia
            pygame.display.update()
            reloj.tick(15)

        elif estadoJuego == JUGANDO:
            pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
            x += cambioEnX  # Se actualiza la posición de la imagen
            yObstaculo += velocidad  # Se actuliza la posición de 'y' del obstaculo
            yObstaculoDos += velocidadDos  # Se actualiza la posición de 'y' del segundo obstáculo
            yObstaculoTres += velocidadTres  # Se actualiza la posición de 'y' del tercer obstáculo
            yMoneda += velocidadMoneda  # Se actuliza la posición de 'y' de la moneda
            ventanaDeJuego.blit(fondoJuego, (0, 0))  # Se dibuja el fondo del juego
            dibujarPersonaje(ventanaDeJuego, imagenMario, x, y)  # Se dibuja el personaje
            dibujarObstaculoUno(ventanaDeJuego, imagenObstaculo, xObstaculo, yObstaculo)  # Se dibuja un obstáculo
            dibujarObstaculoDos(ventanaDeJuego, imagenObstaculoDos, xObstaculoDos, yObstaculoDos)  # Se dibuja otro obstáculo
            dibujarObstaculoTres(ventanaDeJuego, imagenObstaculoTres, xObstaculoTres, yObstaculoTres)  # Otro obstáculo
            dibujarMoneda(ventanaDeJuego, imagenMoneda, xMoneda, yMoneda)  # Se dibuja la moneda
            hacerPuntaje(ventanaDeJuego, monedasColectadas)  # Se imprime el contador de monedas

            ### Limites de para la pantalla ###
            if x > ANCHO - anchoImagen or x < 0:
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                sonidoColision.play()
                dibujarPerdio(ventanaDeJuego, fondoPerdio, sonidoPerdio)
                estadoJuego = MENU  # Se vuelve al menu
            ### Limites de para la pantalla ###

            ### Actualización de posición de los obstáculos ###
            if yObstaculo > ALTO:  # Condición para saber si el objeto sale de la pantalla
                yObstaculo = 0 - altoObstaculo  # Al hacerlo, su posición en 'y' debe ser como la original
                xObstaculo = random.randrange(0, ANCHO)  # También se genera una nueva posición en 'x'

            if yObstaculoDos > ALTO:  # Condición para saber si el objeto sale de la pantalla
                yObstaculoDos = 0 - altoObstaculoDos  # Al hacerlo, su posición en 'y' debe ser como la original
                xObstaculoDos = random.randrange(0, ANCHO)  # También se genera una nueva posición en 'x'

            if yObstaculoTres > ALTO:  # Condición para saber si el objeto sale de la pantalla
                yObstaculoTres = 0 - altoObstaculoTres  # Al hacerlo, su posición en 'y' debe ser como la original
                xObstaculoTres = random.randrange(0, ANCHO)  # También se genera una nueva posición en 'x'
            ### Actualización de posición de los obstáculos ###

            ### Actualización de posición de moneda ###
            if yMoneda > ALTO:  # Condición para saber si el objeto sale de la pantalla
                yMoneda = 0 - altoMoneda  # Al hacerlo, su posición en 'y' debe ser como la original
                xMoneda = random.randrange(0, ANCHO)  # También se genera una nueva posición en 'x'
            ### Actualización de posición de moneda ###

            ### Colsiones con obstáculos ###
            if y < yObstaculo + altoObstaculo:
                if x > xObstaculo and x < xObstaculo + anchoObstaculo or x + anchoImagen > xObstaculo and x + anchoImagen < xObstaculo + anchoObstaculo:
                    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                    sonidoColision.play()
                    dibujarPerdio(ventanaDeJuego, fondoPerdio, sonidoPerdio)
                    estadoJuego = MENU  # Se vuelve al menu
            if y < yObstaculoDos + altoObstaculoDos:
                if x > xObstaculoDos and x < xObstaculoDos + anchoObstaculoDos or x + anchoImagen > xObstaculoDos and x + anchoImagen < xObstaculoDos + anchoObstaculoDos:
                    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                    sonidoColision.play()
                    dibujarPerdio(ventanaDeJuego, fondoPerdio, sonidoPerdio)
                    estadoJuego = MENU  # Se vuelve al menu
            if y < yObstaculoTres + altoObstaculoTres:
                if x > xObstaculoTres and x < xObstaculoTres + anchoObstaculoTres or x + anchoImagen > xObstaculoTres and x + anchoImagen < xObstaculoTres + anchoObstaculoTres:
                    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                    sonidoColision.play()
                    dibujarPerdio(ventanaDeJuego, fondoPerdio, sonidoPerdio)
                    estadoJuego = MENU  # Se vuelve al menu
            ### Colsiones con obstáculos ###

            ### Colisiones con moneda ###
            if y < yMoneda + altoMoneda:
                if x > xMoneda and x < xMoneda + anchoMoneda or x + anchoImagen > xMoneda and x + anchoImagen < xMoneda + anchoMoneda:
                    yMoneda = 0 - altoMoneda  # Se regresa a la posición 'y' incial
                    xMoneda = random.randrange(0, ANCHO)  # Se genera una nueva posición en 'x' para la moneda
                    sonidoMoneda.play()
                    monedasColectadas += 1  # Se actualiza el contador
                    velocidad += 0.5  # Se incrementa la velocidad con cada vuelta
                    puntosJugador += 1
                    print(puntosJugador)
                    if monedasColectadas >= 5:
                        velocidadDos = 3 + monedasColectadas  # Aparece un nuevo obstáculo
                    if monedasColectadas >= 10:
                        velocidadTres = 6 + monedasColectadas  # Aparece un nuevo obstáculo
            ### Colisiones con moneda ###

        pygame.display.update()  #Se actualiza pygame
        reloj.tick(30)  # Cantidad de FPS

    pygame.quit()  #Se cierra pygame

    if puntosJugador > int(puntosOriginales):
        with open("Puntos.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(str(puntosJugador))








'Función main que hara la ejecución del juego'
def main():
    dibujarJuego()  # Se llama a la función que contiene el ciclo principal


main()
```

Ah, y aparte de todo, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Paco/PycharmProjects/Proyecto Final/Pruebas.py", line 388, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Paco/PycharmProjects/Proyecto Final/Pruebas.py", line 385, in main
    dibujarJuego()  # Se llama a la función que contiene el ciclo principal
  File "C:/Users/Paco/PycharmProjects/Proyecto Final/Pruebas.py", line 367, in dibujarJuego
    pygame.display.update()  #Se actualiza pygame
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que ya sé cual es tu problema. estás abriendo el archivo en modo lectura (r), cuando deberias abrirlo en modo escritura (w), o en modo append (a). El código quedaría así:

```
    archivoPuntos = open("Puntos.txt", "w")

    archivoPuntos.write(puntosOriginales)

    archivoPuntos.close()

    puntosJugador = 0
```

(ten en cuenta que este programa sobreescribe cualquier cosa en el archivo)

por otro lado, es posible que el error que estás teniendo "pygame.error: video system not initialized" es porque estás intentando actualizar la pantalla antes de iniciar pygame con pygame.init()